# manage session for all in php

Tags: php, session, session-state, session-cookies

i have a session variable $_SESSION['random'] and a page home.php .home.php contain a div which are auto refresh and show a random number and this number put into $_SESSION['random'] array .again any number pull from range 1 to 50 and put into $_SESSION['random'] variable . 
my question is that if any user1 is open home.php and 10 number are pull from range and put into $_SESSION['random'] ,if any user2 open that page hoem.php then this colud not start from initial, user2  also have 10 number as they are pullout .
if will possible in session and if then how to ?

Comment: Each user have it's own session vars - so if you want to synchronize the numbers somehow, you have to store a global value in textfile/database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should store the last number pulled into the database and assign the +1 no to the next user,if the number is >50 than reset it back to zero.

without using database you cannot perform this